# Changing user mail location in CentOS with SELinux Enabled

Tags: centos, postfix, selinux

This is an practice RHCE question. I need to change the mail files from `/var/spool/mail/user` to `/var/spool/user`. Note that SELinux must remain enabled at all times.
Will I need to change any folder context or enable any Boolean values?

### Edit:

I know this is not good practice and I wouldn't normally do this.

I know the context of /var/spool has to change to mail_spool_t but that would break other services using it and it was confusing.

Comment: `/var/spool` is used by many different services. Don't just go throwing mail in it, or Bad Things will happen sooner or later. This is why it's in `/var/spool/mail` to begin with.

Comment: i wouldn't normally do that .. but as i said this is an actual RHCE exam question

Comment: I rather doubt that the _real_ RHCE exam will ask you to do something that is not only impossible but violates best practices so egregiously. I don't know what exam you're looking at, but I suspect you wasted your money on it.

Comment: lol thanks for confirming my doubts ... and i didn't pay money for it thank god :D

Answer (score 2):

The file context for mail spool files is `mail_spool_t`. You will need to use `semanage` and `chcon` to set it on the new location.

Comment: thanks for the answer ...  but isnt /var/spool itself already have var_spool_t won't changing it break something else

Comment: @kamelion If the question is a simple "How would you go about..." (i.e. purely theoretical), the answer above is how you'd do it. If the question is practical, the answer is "You shouldn't do that. It's ***Bad And Wrong***, violates [the Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), and will make the next sysadmin want to cause you serious bodily harm".

Comment: that's what i thought .. i had to make sure ... thanks